# Transform start and end times to density/occupation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with start and end times (in seconds) for vehicle's journeys in a city. I want to generate a graphic for the city's occupation, in other terms, how many vehicles there were throughout time.
So what I have is something like:

```
id | startTime | endTime 
1  | 3.1       | 78.0 
2  | 23.1      | 112.7
3  | 31.1      | 112.4
```

My final goal is to analyze the data from a 1 hour (3600 seconds) simulation, but I am currently using a smaller set to try things out.

So the graphic should have the number of cars on the Y axis, and the time of observation on the X axis. The final result should look like:
[Example from PREXT paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPrzi.png). Unfortunatly in the paper they don't mention how they plotted this.

What's the best way to solve this, that will still work for the 1 hour version?

I'm trying to use pandas for this, but I'm new to it, and after a lot of googling around (date scaffolding, density plotting...) I can't find any suitable answers. I apologise in advance if there is already a similar question, I've tried to find it to the best of my ability and failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how to generate the points you need to feed to the plotting routine.  All of the rest is well-documented technique.

Very simply, you need a running sum of cars in the city.  Convert your two columns above to a simple sequence of transactions: +1 when a car enters, -1 when it leaves:

```
  3.1    +1
 78.0    -1
 23.1    +1
112.7    -1
 31.1    +1
112.4    -1
```

Sort this series by time.  Then make a running sum of the right column.  This gives you a running count of the auto population throughout the hour.

Give that set of points (time, count), you should be able to handle the rest of the coding to get your graphs.